# How to move the camera in an endless runner game along with the rocket

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Currently I am experiencing issues with changing the position of the main camera in unity via a c# script. I am trying to change the camera's position along with the rocket. So ideally it should have the rocket a bit offset on the left of the screen. It should follow along during playing the game.

This is my camera script which should follow the Target "TheRocket" inside unity when I press play.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CameraScript : MonoBehaviour {

    Camera mainCam;
    public Transform target;
    public float distance = 15.0f;
    public float cameraY = 1.0f;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        Vector3 pos = transform.position;
        pos.z = target.position.z - distance;
        pos.x = target.position.x + 18;
    }

    void LateUpdate () {
        mainCam = Camera.main;
        Vector3 temp = mainCam.transform.position;
        temp.y = cameraY;
    }
}
```

**My Controls class looks as following:**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Controls : MonoBehaviour {

    public float speed = 8.0f;
    public float jumpspeed = 20.5f;
    public float gravity = 20.0f;
    Vector3 moveDirection = Vector3.zero;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        CharacterController controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
        if(controller.isGrounded) {
            moveDirection = new Vector3(0, 0, Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") + 3);
            moveDirection = transform.TransformDirection(moveDirection);
            moveDirection *= speed;
        }

        if(Input.GetButtonDown("Jump")) {
            moveDirection.y += jumpspeed;
        }else{
            if(Input.GetButtonDown("Jump")){
                moveDirection.y += jumpspeed;
            }
        }

        moveDirection.y -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;
        controller.Move(moveDirection * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

I honestly have no idea what I am doing wrong here. I used this tutorial as a reference :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O0CxA3I2eYQ

Hopefully someone can find out where the problems hides itself!

Screenshots

**Scene**

[image]

**Scene playing (should follow the rocket and being zoomed in as well**

[image]

**Main Camera Inspector View**

[image]

**TheRocket**

[image]

Comment: I'd start with describing what _actual problem_ you are experiencing....

Comment: @RobIII Sure. I added some boilet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have not set the cameras position anywhere in your script, you have only made a copy of the cameras position and placed it into the `pos` variable. You need to then set the cameras position equal to your variable.

This should be all you need:

```
void LateUpdate()
{
    Vector3 pos = target.transform.position;
    pos.z = target.position.z - distance;
    pos.x = target.position.x + 18;
    Camera.main.transform.position = pos;
}
```

Comment: You also have make similar correction in the [`Update`](https://youtu.be/O0CxA3I2eYQ?t=790) function.

Comment: Thanks bud.. What is the mistake in the Update Function?

Comment: You can remove the stuff in Update

Comment: I mean that you do not need both Update and LateUpdate. All you need is what I have above

Answer (score 2):

Hard to tell based on the information. But my first guess is that you haven't attached the camera to the rocket and assigned variables appropriately.

In Unity you would drag the camera onto the rocket so that the camera becomes a child of rocket.

Comment: What do you need to give a proper answer? I have attached the rocket to the Target variable inside the unity inspector.

Comment: Explain what the problem is. Is the camera just not moving at all? What behaviors are you experiencing? Include a screenshot of the unity hierarchy maybe. Also be sure that you have attached the scripts to the appropriate objects.

Comment: See updated question. It does not move. It should move together with the rocket.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps to follow :

1- Drag the rocket to the scene

2- Create a camera and drag it to be a child of the rocket

3- Position the camera wherever you want to face the rocket (like the position in the screenshot)

4- Save the rocket as a prefab and Instantiate it each time you want to fire a rocket, the camera will be attached to the rocket.

I did this last week on a rocket launcher where the rocket is fired and a camera follows it until it explodes